# Remove the letters of a word at a time

Tags: python

From a string

```
t = "abcde"
```

I would like to print in output a list like

```
1.abcd

2.abc

3.ab

4.a
```

Comment: I suggest string slicing.

Comment: You can use slicing and list comprehension. For instance t[:-1] is "abcd".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. Please state clearly the programming problem, attempted solutions and other relevant information, as recommended in the Help Center.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One approach is to simply trim off the last character of the string in each iteration of a loop until there are no characters left. You can use *string slicing* to get a substring of `t`, for instance `t[:4]` gives the first four characters of `t`. More to the point, `t[:-1]` gives all but the *last* carachter of `t`, which is what you want. You can use len(t) to check the number of characters in `t`, and use a `while` loop to iterate until there are no characters left.

```
t = "abcde"
while len(t) > 0:
    t = t[:-1]
    if len(t) > 0:
        print t
```

Just for kicks, you can also do it in a one-liner using `join` and *generator* statements:

```
print "\n".join(t[:-i] for i in xrange(1,5))
```

Comment: can you write this without the `if`?

Comment: Sure, but why? The reason for the `if` is because the question shows that the full string (i.e., `"abcde"`) should not be printed, so I trim the string before printing it. But it also doesn't show the empty string, so I use the `if` to make sure I'm not printing the empty string. There are other ways to do it without using an `if`, but what is the problem with using it?

Comment: I think this looks bad, perhaps you can check `> 1` in the while condition?

Comment: Yep, you sure can. There are lots of other ways to do it. This is how I did it.

Answer (score 2):

```
t = "abcde"
for i in range(len(t)-1,0,-1): #where i is each item in the list from the size of the string, less 1, to zero
  print t[0:i] # print from start of string until i
```

Comment: Doesn't _exactly_ match what the OP asked for. Yours includes the full string, the original question does not.

Comment: Fixed it, to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for index, letter in enumerate(string[:-1]):
    print index + 1, string[:-index - 1]
```

This should help you! You might have to modify this according to your need.

Comment: Pretty cute, but it prints the a fifth line, containing the empty string. The OP only specified four lines of output.

Comment: Note: Answer was fixed to account for my previous comment.